# File remains open by process System(4) for about 2 minutes after closed

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I just moved my project from Win Vista/VB 2010 express to Win 7/VS 2013 express and a strange problem appeared:

1-  I open VS, compile the project (let’s call it program.exe), start debugging (i.e. I press F5) and everything goes fine.

2-  I close my program and it ends gracefully, nothing remains open and it disappears from task manager. I can even rename or delete program.exe and Windows doesn’t complain.

3-  If I make a small change to the code and try to build again and then I get the message “Could not copy program.exe. The program cannot access the file program.exe because it’s being used by another process”.

4-  If I wait a couple of minutes and try to build again then the build is successful and I can run the program normally.

As I said, program.exe ends gracefully and I can even delete it manually. In fact, to make sure I’m not leaving anything open I made a change in the main procedure of my project and call Return as soon as it starts in order to terminate it immediately, but that doesn’t change the described behavior.

I used Process Hacker (a more advanced task manager) to search for the process and it doesn’t show program.exe running either, but if use the “Find handles or DLLs” function and look for “program.exe” then it says that the file is held open by process “System (4)”. Once “System (4)” releases the file after 2 or 3 minutes then VS can build it again.

I have enabled and disabled vshost but that doesn’t help. Closing and reopening VS doesn't help either. The only things that works and let me rebuild is either waiting 2 or 3 minutes or deleting process.exe manually.

Do you have any idea on what’s going on here? Is there some service keeping the file open more time than necessary?

I never experienced this problem with the same project on my old Vista/VB 2010 machine. I’m running a clean / original windows 7 installation with latest service pack and updates (just installed on a new hard drive a couple days ago) and I just ran a complete virus check and found nothing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: The fake "System" process is where device drivers and kernel code lives.  And anti-malware, the common scourge on programmers' machines.  You do *not* want to give it a wedgie when your compiler lets an executable file appear from nowhere.  Make an exclusion for your project directories.  Get rid of it completely if it is Avast.